# Does anyone have the link to Lakulisa Pasupatha Sutras

Tags: pashupata-shaivism

I am looking for the Lakulisa Pasupatha Sutras. Does anyone have the link to it? I am looking for Sanskrit version along with its English translation available anywhere.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You read Lakulisha's Pashupata Sutras in Sanskrit and English, along with Kaundinya's Panchartha Bhashya in English, [here](https://archive.org/details/PasupataSutramHaripadaChakroborti).

And you can read both the Pashupata Sutras and the Panchartha Bhashya in Sanskrit [here](https://archive.org/details/PasupataSutrasPhotocopy1940ChitrodayaManjariTrivandrumSanskritSeriesCXLIII).

Comment: Well sanskrit link is not working... Do u have any other link?